# Оптимизация SQL запроса (CPU 100%)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем привет! Имею такой код:

```
        $key_cache = 'cache_banners_tpl_'. $idpl;
        $dateNow = date(MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT);
        $dateTimeNow = date("H:i:s");
        if(($banners = $this->app->cache5min->get($key_cache)) === NULL) {
          $find_items = array();
          $banners = $this->app->db->fetchAll("SELECT b.id,b.active,b.richmedia,b.rich_position,b.ip_limit,b.cookie_limit,b.cookie_interval,b.day_limit,b.limit_interval,b.frequency,
                                         b.close_btn, b.use_geo, bpl.s_x, bpl.s_y FROM bs_items_places AS bp
                                         LEFT JOIN bs_items AS b ON b.id = bp.item_id
                                         LEFT JOIN bs_places AS bpl ON bpl.id = bp.place_id
                                         WHERE b.active = 1 AND b.date_start < '".$dateNow."' AND b.date_stop > '".$dateNow."'
                                         AND bpl.active = 1 AND bp.place_id = {$idpl}
                                         AND (IF((time_from!='00:00:00' AND time_to!='00:00:00'),(time_from<='".$dateTimeNow."' AND time_to>='".$dateTimeNow."'),1))
                                         GROUP BY b.id
                                         ORDER BY b.frequency DESC, b.day_limit DESC
                                          ");
        foreach($banners AS $bnr) {
            $find_items[$bnr['id']] = $bnr;
        }
        $banners = $find_items;
        $this->app->cache5min->save($key_cache,$banners);
    }
```

EXPLAIN запроса:

```
explain SELECT `bs_items_ip`.`id`, `bs_items_ip`.`item_id`, `bs_items_ip`.`place_id`, `bs_items_ip`.`date_show`, `bs_items_ip`.`ip`, `bs_items_ip`.`shows` FROM `bs_items_ip` WHERE `bs_items_ip`.`item_id` = 146 AND `bs_items_ip`.`ip` = '94.100.184.101' AND `bs_items_ip`.`date_show` = '2017-05-29' LIMIT 1;

+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | bs_items_ip | ref  | item_id       | item_id | 5       | const | 580178 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

меня очень сильно он грузит процессор, можно ли его каким-то образом оптимизировать? Чтобы процессор не грузил, ибо из-за этого плохо работает сайт. Как только я убираю и комментирую этот код, нагрузка сразу спадает.

Comment: для начала нужно сделать `EXPLAIN ТУТ_ТВОЙ_ЗАПРОС` ..... и посмотреть результаты... во-вторых надо посмотреть есть ли у тебя индексы в таблицах

Comment: а время `time_from` вместо нулей нельзя на `NULL` сделать?

Comment: Добавил explain

Comment: Вы explain сделайте именно для того запроса, по которому вопрос. Сейчас вы почему то сделали его для другого запроса на одну таблицу да еще с лимитом. и отформатируйте его что бы читабельный был (как код выделите)

Comment: Это один из запросов выполняется, можно ли каким-то образом предотвратить эти 500+к записей

Comment: Можно. надо построить индекс по какому нибудь из полей используемых в where. или по нескольким полям. желательно что бы индекс обеспечил высокую селективность, т.е. что бы с искомым значением ключа было мало записей. И индекс надо так придумать, что бы его можно было использовать в большинстве подобных запросов.

Comment: нет причем тут индекс? Запрос использует индексы, добавишь или нет индексы результат селекта будет тот же, просто с индексами быстрее

Comment: что значит "предотвратить 500+к записей", если вы запрос так написали, куда вы хотите часть данных выкинуть? Разберитесь, это корректный результат или нет. Если корректный, то возможно вам нужны не все строки, а только часть. Если вы ожидаете меньше результатов чем получаете, то видимо, недостаточно условий написано?

Answer (score 3):

1. Замените LEFT JOIN на INNER - всё равно связывания внутренние (секция WHERE такая);
2. Ещё лучше - перепишите на картезианку с отборами;
3. Добавьте алиасы таблиц КАЖДОМУ полю (а то неясно, из какой таблицы взяты поля time_from и time_to);
4. А потом смотрите EXPLAIN.

   ```
   SELECT b.id, b.active, b.richmedia, b.rich_position, b.ip_limit
        , b.cookie_limit, b.cookie_interval, b.day_limit, b.limit_interval
        , b.frequency, b.close_btn, b.use_geo, bpl.s_x, bpl.s_y 
   FROM bs_items_places AS bp,
        bs_items AS b,
        bs_places AS bpl 
   WHERE b.active = 1 
     AND b.id = bp.item_id
     AND bpl.id = bp.place_id
     AND b.date_start < '".$dateNow."' 
     AND b.date_stop > '".$dateNow."'
     AND bpl.active = 1 AND bp.place_id = {$idpl}
     AND (IF((time_from != '00:00:00' AND time_to != '00:00:00'), (time_from <= '".$dateTimeNow."' AND time_to >= '".$dateTimeNow."'), 1))
   GROUP BY b.id
   ORDER BY b.frequency DESC, b.day_limit DESC
   ```

Ну и полностью согласен с Denis - есть смысл убрать группировку. А если нужна только одна запись для каждого b.id - то её оставить, а поля bpl.s_x, bpl.s_y обернуть любой групповой функцией (скажем, MIN).

А также, если PHP-сервер с MySQL-сервером в одном часовом поясе, то уберите подстановку текущих даты и времени из PHP и вставьте соответствующие MySQL-функции.

Comment: "In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents" Первые два пункта - одна сущность. Ну и "картезианка" - это вообще интересный термин (каждый понимает в меру своей испорченности) :)

Comment: @tutankhamun Всё так. Просто когда запрос пишется с использованием JOIN, то условия связывания "размазываются" по тексту запроса, а вот когда используется прямое (декартово, картезианское) произведение таблиц, то все условия отбора (сейчас не говорим, само собой, о секции HAVING) оказываются в одном блоке - это несколько упрощает построение "правильных" для данного запроса индексов.

Answer (score 3):

Как минимум, могу посоветовать по sql запросу:

1. Не используйте `left join`, когда накладываете на присоединяемую таблицу условия потом в `where`, таким образом у вас `left join` превращается в `join`. Пишите сразу обычный `join`, он отрабатывает быстрее.
2. Зачем используете `group by` без агрегирующих функций? Это вызывает дополнительную нагрузку.
3. Можете подумать над вашим `IF` в `WHERE`, возможно, это условие можно переписать гораздо проще.

В результате ваш запрос будет примерно таким:

```
SELECT b.id, b.active, b.richmedia, b.rich_position, 
    b.ip_limit, b.cookie_limit, b.cookie_interval,
    b.day_limit, b.limit_interval, b.frequency,
    b.close_btn, b.use_geo, bpl.s_x, bpl.s_y 
FROM bs_items_places AS bp
    JOIN bs_items AS b ON b.id = bp.item_id
    JOIN bs_places AS bpl ON bpl.id = bp.place_id
WHERE b.active = 1 AND b.date_start < '".$dateNow."' AND b.date_stop > '".$dateNow."'
    AND bpl.active = 1 AND bp.place_id = {$idpl}
    AND (IF((time_from!='00:00:00' AND time_to!='00:00:00'),
            (time_from<='".$dateTimeNow."' AND time_to>='".$dateTimeNow."'),1))
ORDER BY b.frequency DESC, b.day_limit DESC
```

Comment: Не помогло, нагрузка все равно не падает

Comment: @DronaxD, EXPLAIN запроса сделайте и результат добавьте в свой вопрос.

Comment: Добавил explain, возвращает 580 тысяч результатов это очень много